# What is citation index?

Tags: publications, citations

What is citation index?
How are such indices calculated?
How can any journal become part of an index?
These are my questions about various indexes that are used at academic environments.

Comment: Have you read [Citation index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_index) wiki page?

Comment: They are indexed if someone (like Web of Knowledge, in the wiki) considers them important enough to be indexed.

Comment: Is there any special formula to calculate them? How can I know which journals are listed in any indexes? How can I know reliability of one journal?

Comment: The formula is simple: the average number of cites their papers get after X time. To see the contents of an index, check the index. What defines reliability for you?

Comment: Reliability is power of any journal on academic world. For example which journal accepted as scientific and accept only strong articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an entire field dedicated to answering the question about how to measure scholarly impact.

Two indices that you could probably compute by hand in a little bit of time are the h-index and the g-index.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-index

Also, if you are an author thinking about submitting a draft, and looking for a good journal in your field, one place to look is on Google Scholar. Go to scholar.google.com, then click on `metrics'. Google has auto calculated the h-index and g-index for the last five years of a lot of different journals in different fields. Generally speaking journals with higher h or g numbers are going to be better places to publish. (Not an ironclad rule, so check with a trusted advisor before sending something out, but a good rule of thumb)

If you are an editor of a journal and you want your journal indexed, then just write to the editor of Journal Citation Reports and ask about the process to be included. Be prepared for a lengthy wait though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_Citation_Reports